# AWS SQS and other services

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

my company has a messaging system which sends real-time messages in JSON format, and it's not built on AWS
our team is trying to use AWS SQS to receive these messages, which will then have DynamoDB to storage this messages
im thinking to use EC2 to read this messages then save them 
any better solution ?? or how to do it i don't have a good experience

Comment: We need some more information.  While you can certainly use SQS there may be better solutions.  To read from SQS you have to poll the queue - it is not event driven.  SNS is event driven and, coupled with an AWS Lambda, could save your events anywhere you want including a DynamoDB.  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?  What kind of volume do you have?  Is the destination only DynamoDB?  What if an event gets lost?  How real-time is real-time for your environment?

Comment: what i really use is a gateway . (they use the SQS ) they will send a data (like a MAC address + few more information) so i want to read this data and put them in DynamoDB.i will receive this data every 3 seconds and no need to worry if i lost a data 3 or 4 times in each minute (just example ). can you help me ?

Comment: @stdunbar can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All EC2 is infrastructure on Cloud, It is similar to physical machine with OS on local setup. If you want to create any application that will fetch the data from Amazon SQS(Messages in Json Format) and Push it in dynamodb(No Sql database), Your design is correct as both SQS and DynamoDb have thorough Json Support. Once your application is ready then you deploy that application on EC2 machine.

For achieving this, your application must have the asyc Buffered SQS consumer that will consume the messages(limit of sqs messages is 256KB), Hence whichever application is publishing messages size of messages needs to be less thab 256Kb.
Please refer below link for sqs consumer

[is putting sqs-consumer to detect receiveMessage event in sqs scalable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810786/is-putting-sqs-consumer-to-detect-receivemessage-event-in-sqs-scalable/48823813#48823813)

Once you had consumed the message from sqs queue you need to save it in dynamodb, that you can easily do it using **crud repository**. With Repository you can directly save the json in Dynamodb table but please sure to configure the provisioning write capacity based on requests, because more will be the provisioning capacity more will be the cost. Please refer below link for configuring the write capacity of table.

[Dynamodb reading and writing units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999465/dynamodb-reading-and-writing-units/44178010#44178010)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'll have a setup something like this:

[image]

The EC2 instances (one or more) will read your queue every few seconds to see if there is anything there.  If so, they will write this data to DynamoDB.

Based on what you're saying you'll have less than 1,000,000 reads from SQS in a month so you can start out on the free tier for that.  You can have a single EC2 instance initially and that can be a very small instance - a T2.micro should be more than sufficient.  And you don't need more than a few writes per second on DynamoDB.

The advantage of SQS is that if for some reason your EC2 instance is temporarily unavailable the messages continue to queue up and you won't lose any of them.

From a coding perspective, you don't mention your development environment but there are AWS libraries available for a pretty wide variety of environments.  I develop in Java and the code to do this would be *maybe* 100 lines.  I would guess that other languages would be similar.  Make sure you look at long polling in the language you're using - it can help to speed up the processing and save you money.